# Program returning "could not get audio input stream from input file" for specific .WAV file

Tags: java, matlab, audio, signal-processing, wav

I have a program that involves the analysis and output of .wav files. It works perfectly fine with tracks from cds or the internet but I have generated a sequence of pure sine wave tones using matlab to analyse and it is giving me the error shown in the title. The matlab files run fine in iTunes so I'm not sure why my program is having trouble with it.

```
public static void signalToFile(File f) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException
{
    AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f);
    int numBytes = inputStream.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[numBytes];
    inputStream.read(buffer, 0, numBytes);

    String newFile = f.getName().replace(".wav", ".txt");
    System.out.println("Beginning file write: " + newFile + " (soundUtilities)");
    BufferedWriter fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("src/examples/Media/" + newFile)));
    System.out.println("Ending file write: " + newFile + " (soundUtilities)");
    System.out.println(buffer.length);
    ByteBuffer myBB = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
    myBB.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    while(myBB.remaining() > 1)
    {
        short current = myBB.getShort();
        fileOut.write(String.valueOf(current));
        fileOut.newLine();
    }

    fileOut.flush();
    fileOut.close();
    inputStream.close();
}
```

The first line of this method is what is causing the error. This method involves the signal information for the file to a txt file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the small section of matlab code I used to create the wav file:

```
x13 = sin(2*pi*220*t1); % A3 long sample
x13envelope = [1:-1/length(x13):1/length(x13)];
x13full = x13.*x13envelope;

totalSound = [x1full x2full x3full x4full x5full x6full x7full x8full x9full x10full x11full x12full x13full]; % combines the notes

 wavwrite(totalSound, fs, 32, 'TestTune');
```

Each of the entries in the "totalSound" array represent a note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WAV files](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) have a header. You don't seem to create that header. What you seem to create is a raw PCM file.

Comment: @9000 I will add the section of matlab code I used to create the wav file, but I am assuming that if I didn't make the header for the wav file then it wouldn't play in iTunes?

Comment: iTunes could be smart enough to accept raw PCM. Still open a good .wav file with a file viewer (or just F3 in far or mc) and see if it starts with `RIFF`.

Comment: @Joneser: "I am assuming that if I didn't make the header for the wav file then it wouldn't play in iTunes?"  That is a rash assumption.  Most players go to extraordinary lengths to parse invalid media files.

Comment: @9000 I have opened both my working files and the file causing this error and they all start with RIFF

Comment: OK, then the problem is elsewhere. I'd try opening a problematic file in an audio editor and see what it looks like, or how the editor would complain.

Comment: I did a little more work on this and found that you were indeed correct, even though the generated .wav file had a RIFF headier, I can only assume that it was not properly formed, as when I used iTunes to "Create Wav File" on the generated wav, it changed the structure of the file and it then worked. Thanks a million guys.

Answer (score 0):

I exepriences this problem "The output is different in JBoss 4.2 and JBoss 7
JBoss 4.2:
Support WAVE = true

JBoss 7:
Support WAVE = false"
check also this https://community.jboss.org/message/729654